# What version of CXF should I use?

Tags: java, cxf

I have been updating some of my example CXF programs.  I thought the best approach to selecting the correct version would be to check CXF out from apache and build it on my machine.  What I found was that for the latest versions of CXF (2.7.4, 2.7.5), I run into permgen out-of-memory errors during the build process.  It is too much to expect that that this framework will build cleanly without tuning my maven settings?  Sorry for the rant, but I just waisted time with a CXF upgrade where the codegen options changed significantly.

Sorry for stomping on open source developer efforts like this.  I hope you understand.

thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build with additional memory setting?  This issue is documented with [work around/solution](http://cxf.apache.org/building.html)

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M"
```

You could try even larger value.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  @DanKulp suggested the same thing.  Here is is tweet: "@dbarber Did you follow the instructions in CXF's BUILDING.txt file?  MAVEN_OPTS is very important."  

From the ./distribution/src/main/release/BUILDING.txt file, they suggest 

2) Set the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to include more memory
   Unix/Linux/OSX   $> export MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Xmx768M"
   Windows          > set MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Xmx768M"